# How to use Google OAuth2.0 without out-of-band (OOB)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have created new OAuth 2.0 Client IDs (application type = Desktop app). Then downloaded the OAuth client JSON file. Put the file into the folder where my code is looking. When I run the code locally on my PC it`s try to open following URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={my_client_id}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope={my_scope}&access_type=offline&response_type=code
```

and that is what I expect. Since the downloaded OAuth client has the parameter "redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]. So I expected the same thing when I ran this same code on the ubuntu server, but nope. The URL it proposes me visit is

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={my_client_id}&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope={my_scope}&access_type=offline&response_type=code
```

And here is the problem, I don't understand what I have to do to make my server pass this authorization.
I already tried to manually change this parameter of redirect_uris before visiting the destination to the same one I had on my local computer - to **http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F**, but I got this error in the browser:[image]

Who can help me? What should I do?

Comment: Is `redirect_uris` in your question a typo? When you run it locally it looks good, as the URL it wants to open has a `redirect_uri` with `localhost`. But on the server the URL you have given contains the OOB URI. In both cases (a) I expect you want to have a `localhost` `redirect_uri`, if this really is a desktop app; and (b) you need to make the desktop app run a web server so that the `localhost` URI actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developers using installed applications need to stitch to using IP flow.

[Loopback IP address (macOS, Linux, Windows desktop)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#redirect-uri_loopback)

A key point on that page is

> To receive the authorization code using this URL, **your application must be listening on the local web server**.

So as directed you would use `http://127.0.0.1:port or http://[::1]:port` The fact that you are getting a page not found is working as intended as you just have not set up the local web server as directed in the documetnation.

The authorization code needed for authorization can still be found in the URL browser.  Currently this is the only information we have from Google and there is no other solution.